# can't get the data from database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i created a function to get data from the database but it's not working i don't know what's wrong 
here is the code :

```
    <?php
function Connect_Show($server_name,$server_user,$server_pass,$db,$db_table){
$connect =  mysql_connect($server_name,$server_user,$server_pass) or die ('error , can not connect to database ') ; 
$select =  mysql_Select_db($db) or die (' error , can not select the database '); 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table order by id ")
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
echo $rows['id'];
echo $rows['name'];
echo $rows['emails'];
echo $rows['password'];             
}}       
 echo Connect_Show("localhost","root","root","learn","users");
?>
```

Comment: What's wrong is bad indenting, bad capitalization, and bad use of the deprecated `mysql_` instead of `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: And missing semi-colon.  And no checks for errors after some of the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo Connect_Show("localhost","root","root","learn","users");
```

Just use this:

```
Connect_Show("localhost","root","root","learn","users");

Connect_Show is a function, with echo commands in it, its not returning anything.
```